# influxDB return 0 instead of 'no results'

Tags: influxdb

we are using the influxDB for statistics and dashboards. We love it! Blazing fast and easy to integrate. However we are stuck when we launch new features.

We have the following FLUX query. A massive database with all "model_events" based on the businessUUID. However if the business doesn't have a `car.created` it returns `no results` instead of a range with 0's. If it has one `car.created` even without the range it will return a 0 range. Is there a possibility to always get the range even if the `_measurement` doesn't have a value?

```
from(bucket: "_events")
    |> range(start: 2022-09-01, stop: 2022-09-11)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "car.created")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["business_uuid"] == "055ade92-ecd9-47b1-bf85-c1381d0afd22")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: count, createEmpty: true)
    |> yield(name: "amount")
```

BTW.... a bit new to InfluxDB...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a dummy table and `union()` it like:

```
import "experimental/array"

rows = [{_time: now(), _field: "someField", _value: 0}]
dummy = array.from(rows: rows)

data = from(bucket: "_events")
    |> range(start: 2022-09-01, stop: 2022-09-11)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "car.created")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["business_uuid"] == "055ade92-ecd9-47b1-bf85-c1381d0afd22")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: count, createEmpty: true)
    |> yield(name: "amount")

union(tables: [dummy, data])
```